# What is causing JLabel not to update?

Tags: java, swing, observer-pattern

Im using Observer Pattern to display whos turn it is to play. And im being given the right data from my Observable, thats why i dont post it. As you can see, the text is being set, as i can get call label.getText().
How come the label wont update?

Ive tried repaint, revalidate, SwingUtilities.invokeLater, updateUI, and all sort of stuff. I do not know what im doing wrong.

Thank you in advanced.

```
public class PlayersTurnPane extends JPanel implements Observer {

    private JLabel label = new JLabel();

    public PlayersTurnPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.gray);
        label.setText("White");
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(getWidth() / 2);
        label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25));
        add(label);

    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
        label.setText((String)arg1); //But it will not update label
        System.out.println(label.getText()); //The text is being set
    }

}
```

My Observable

```
 public class TurnObserver extends Observable {

    public TurnObserver(PlayersTurnPane playersTurnPane) {
        addObserver(playersTurnPane);
    }

    public void setTurn(String turn){
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(turn);
        clearChanged();
    }

}
```

Where i send the data

```
private TurnObserver turnObserver = new TurnObserver(new PlayersTurnPane());    

public void grabPiece(BoardTile boardTile) {
        if(focusedPiece != null && playerTurn.getCurrentTurn() == focusedPiece.getPieceColor()) {
            boardTile.add(focusedPiece);
            updateUI();
            playerTurn.changeTurn();
            turnObserver.setTurn(playerTurn.getCurrentTurn());
        }
    }
```

The panel is added here

```
public class EastPanel extends JPanel {

    public EastPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));
        add(new TimePane());
        add(new MoveHistoryPane());
        add(new PlayersTurnPane());
    }

}
```

Comment: Consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Answer (score 2):

If `System.out.println(label.getText());` is being printed, then you've got a Swing threading issue in code not shown, likely due to long-running code being run on the Swing event thread, preventing this thread from doing its job -- like painting the updated text on the JLabel. Be sure that all long running code is done on a background thread and that Swing state changes and queries are made on the Swing event thread. Read [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for the details.

re,

> And im being given the right data from my Observable, thats why i dont post it.

But it's that unposted code which holds the key to your problem.

---

Dang, Mad is correct: you're shadowing:

```
public TurnObserver() {
    addObserver(new PlayersTurnPane());
}
```

You're adding a ***new*** PlayersTurnPane as your observer, but it's likely not the displayed PlayersTurnPane! Key: every time you call ***new*** on a constructor, you create a ***new*** object, here a PlayersTurnPane. You should pass in the displayed PlayersTurnPane, not a new one.

You've got problems with code like this:

```
public class EastPanel extends JPanel {

    public EastPanel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));
        add(new TimePane());
        add(new MoveHistoryPane());
        add(new PlayersTurnPane());
    }
}
```

The dsiplayed PlayersTurnPane is being created anonymously -- the *object* is being added to a display, but this object is not being referenced by any variable, and this needs to be done if you're going to pass **the exact same PlayersTurnPane object** into the method that makes it an observable.

I suggest that you use class fields and not anonymous objects where you need a reference to the object.  So here, perhaps better would be:

```
public class EastPanel extends JPanel {

    public EastPanel(PlayersTurnPane playersTurnPane) {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0));
        add(new TimePane()); // you likely need parameters for 
        add(new MoveHistoryPane());  // these two objects as well
        add(playersTurnPane);
    }
}
```

The key concept that you seem to be missing is one of the importance of ***references*** which are *pointers* to an object of interest. Read up on this.

Comment: @MadProgrammer: ah, true. You're right, we need a runnable example.

Comment: @user2891133: yep, mad's right -- you're notifying the wrong PlayersTurnPane object, not the one that's displayed!

Comment: Well, that makes a nice change, can you tell me wife :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer: that will do no good. It's like that old Buddist kōan: if a man says something and a woman's not around, is he still wrong?

Comment: Well, that explains a lot :P

Comment: Okai. I see what you mean. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I changed the code, but i still get no update. Apparently i didnt understand what you meant. Sorry for your troubles. May you explain it again?

Comment: @user2891133: you will want to try to understand the concept of *references* better since this is what is needed to solve your problem. Please see edited answer, but for an even better answer, do as Mad suggested in his comment to your original question, create and post a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).